# Объявление переменной с var и без: почему так?

Tags: javascript

Сразу скажу, что [статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/variables) читал, ответа на свой вопрос не нашел.

Итак, последовательно подключается несколько js файлов в подвале.
В первом есть нечто подобное:

```
function funcNAME {
    test.addClass('red'); // добавим класс, просто для примера
}
```

Во втором файле что-то такое:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var test = $('#form_id'); // а тут пусть какая-то форма будет
});
```

При таком варианте, когда переменная объявлена правильным образом (с использованием `var` во втором файле), при вызове функции из первого файла, мы получаем ошибку, что `test` нет. Если же объявить переменную без `var`, то проблем нет, все работает.

Почему так? Без `var` переменная в глобальную как-то превращается или что? Как правильно написать, чтобы данная конструкция работала.

Comment: С `var` переменная объявляется как локальная и видна только в объявленной области видимости. При объявлении переменной без `var` переменная объявляется как глобальная. При объявлении глобальной переменной необходимо проверить существование переменной с таким именем, иначе есть вероятность переписать существующую переменную.

Comment: Читайте статью еще раз) И заодно прочитайте вот эту https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics

Comment: `Без var переменная в глобальную как-то превращается или что?` - да! Но это если не выбран строгий режим (`"use strict";`). Если выбран, получите на этой строке также ошибку. Всегда используйте строгий режим, это правильно!

Comment: @TotalPusher тестил на codepen, если изначально объявить глобальную переменную с `var`, то уже внутри функции если не использовать `var`, то ошибок не будет. Но на всякий случай внутри функций перезаписываю глобальную переменную так window.test = '123'; Вроде, корректно отрабатывает.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko выше дал хорошую ссылку по работе с переменными. Вот `При use strict такой код привёл бы к ошибке, но без него переменная будет создана автоматически, причём в примере выше она создаётся не в функции, а на уровне всего скрипта. Избегайте этого.` Читайте документацию, эксперементируйте. JS он такой, необычный